# Solving $\sin^2x=1-\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

> How would I solve the following trig equation?
>
> $$\sin^2x=1-\cos x$$

I have to write the solution in radians.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall $$\sin^2x = 1 - \cos^2 x$$

So you can write the equation as a quadratic, in $\cos x$:

$$\sin^2x=1-\cos(x)\iff 1 - \cos^2x = 1 - \cos x $$  $$\iff \cos^2 x - \cos x = 0 \iff \cos x(\cos x - 1) = 0$$

Let $u = \cos x$, e.g. $$u(u-1) = 0 \implies u = 0 \text{ or}\;u = 1$$

$$u = \cos x = 0 \; \implies\; x = \frac{(2k + 1)\pi}{2},\; k \in \mathbb Z$$
$$u =  \cos x = 1 \; \implies\; x = 2k\pi, \; k \in \mathbb Z$$

Answer (score 0):

We rewrite

$\sin^2(x)=1-\cos(x)$

as

$1-\cos^2(x)=1-\cos(x),$

so

$-\cos^2(x)=-\cos(x)$

$\cos^2(x)=\cos(x)$

$\cos^2(x)-\cos(x)=0$

$\cos(x)(\cos(x)-1)=0.$

Now:

- ${\cos(x)=0}\quad\Rightarrow\quad{x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi}\ ,\ {k\in\mathbb Z},$
- ${\cos(x)-1=0}\quad\Rightarrow\quad{\cos(x)=1}\quad\Rightarrow\quad{x=2k\pi}\ ,\ {k\in\mathbb Z}.$